# How to specify the languange of "System Settings" it self without rebooting?

Tags: macos, settings, system-settings, language

I want to change the language of **System Settings** App without rebooting. However, it was invalid to select this App in the interface where I can specify a language for an App.
[image]

Comment: Does it have to be persistent? Because you can launch settings in any language in Terminal with `/System/Applications/System\ Settings.app/Contents/MacOS/System\ Settings -AppleLanguages '("en-US")'`

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Yes, it is a good workaround! Thank you!